# Execution failed for task ':react-native-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'

Tags: react-native

I upgraded all packages I am using on my app and then I decided to delete the `node_module` folder as well as `package-lock.json`. I then ran `npm install` and it installed everything but when I try run `npx react-native run-android` it fails with the following error:

**> Execution failed for task ':react-native-location:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.**

I must state that when I installed all packages with `npm install` I had to run it with `--force` flag otherwise it would fail. Not sure if this has anything to do with the current error but just wanted to mention it.

Comment: try cleaning cache of npm and then install again

Answer (score 0):

```
cd android && ./gradlew clean
```

Make sure you run this, when you add some packages in the middle of the development. They try to restart the app by running these commands

```
npx jetify

npx react-native run-android
```